# How to query for existence of child array in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Hello Internet Denizens,

I'm using Firebase at the moment and am trying to query the following structure:

```
items
  1
    - name: "Car"
    - Children
      - 2
      - 3
  2 
    - name: "Wheels"
  3 
    - name: "Engine"
```

You can see from this example that I have an array of items with Ids of 1,2, & 3.  1 also has its own sub-array called Children, which is composed of Ids 2 & 3.

How would I make a firebase query that pulled back only the Ids which had an array called children?

At first, I thought something like the following would work:

```
<my firebase path>.child('items').orderByChild('Children').once('value', function(snap){
    // ... No results :(
});
```

No luck.  Next, I tried adding an attribute called hasChildren = true to the Id of 1 and then queried like so.

```
<my firebase path>.child('items').orderByChild('hasChildren').equalTo(true).once('value', function(snap){
    // ... iterate over results, which in this case is the Id 1
});
```

However, when I do a snap.ForEach(function(data)... and then look at data.val().Children, it's just a blank result, which confuses me because I thought Firebase pulled back all child nodes.  Hence, the need to flatten your data.

How do I get those Children values?

**** Update ** Plunker Added**

http://plnkr.co/edit/9U0ujEwdKi7sgQGmd6IE?p=preview

Looks like this was a comedy of errors.

1) In the simple example, 1, 2, & 3 are ordered, so firebase treats it as an array.  In the real world, those numbers are much more random so firebase treats them as an object since they aren't ordered.

2) For some reason, Intellij wasn't showing the Children object's contents. I had to type in something like data.val().Children['3'] to get a value or something like for(var property in data.val().Children) to iterate through the fields.  Weird.

3) I **STILL** can't do .child('items').orderByChild('Children') ... since that returns all records.  Oddly enough, however, it returns the ones that have Children first.

Comment: What happens if you query using RESTful data structure via the full URL like `https://blistering-inferno-9999.firebaseio.com/items/1/children`?

Comment: @pie-o-pah I receive an array which I can iterator over using snap.forEach so accessing them directly works fine.

Comment: At the line with comment `// Do some stuff` shouldn't you be getting the `data` in that scope? (i.e. callback(data) in there). I suspect you were getting `undefined` because your callback wasn't in the `forEach()` scope.

Comment: @pie-o-pah Yeah, that was a bad example.  Removed.  You can see my plunker and explanation for what was happening.

Comment: It's unclear what your goal is at this point. The code in your plunker is working. If you're not willing to add a hasChildren flag, then yes, simply using orderByChild('Children') will not work. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data The best advice I'd have is to flatten your data, as that's a best-practice for Firebase.

Comment: I didn't want to add the flag since it'd be one more thing to keep in sync.  Looks like I'll have to modify my data structure.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[DataSnapshot.forEach](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html) returns another snapshot in the callback. So instead of trying to access `data['Children']`, you would have to use `data.val().Children`.

Comment: Code posted.  I'm using Intellij so it even returns an empty array in my IDE debugger.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I created a plunker with your code and data structure and it works fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/756IyinB01E1GLtA5SHu Can you create a plunker with all of your code?

Comment: Plunker added.  Put some additional notes in the update section.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like modifying my data structure is the best way to go since checking for the existence of an array object isn't possible at this point.